# Developer-authenticated end users with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

For authenticating end users to things like IoT services, many cloud services have a custom option: The client authenticates with the dev's own server (however the dev implements that), which in turn gets a token from the cloud service and sends that to the client for authentication with the cloud service. [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-2-developer-authenticated-identities/) and [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/identity) are examples of this. This allows for a fully customizable auth.

If I understand correctly, Google Cloud Platform [requires end users to authenticate with Google's OAuth2 service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/), meaning they must sign in with a Google account. I don't see any way around this, but the limitation is so severe that I wonder if I'm missing something. Is there some way I can instead authenticate users my own way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> meaning they must sign in with a Google account

That's not entirely correct, you probably overlooked this in the very doc you referenced (emphasis mine):

> [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) gives you a robust, secure authentication
>   system-in-a-box that helps you do sign in with **any account** your
>   users want to use. Firebase Authentication supports **password
>   authentication in addition to federated sign in with Google, Facebook,
>   Twitter**, and more, allowing you to easily scale your authentication
>   system as you grow on desktop and mobile.

So you can have your users choose their username and password or login using one of their supported 3rd party non-Google accounts.

But it will still be Google handling the authentication for you, which is good if you plan to use other GCP products/services as the authentication can be propaged.

If you want to handle the authentication yourself - nothing stops you from doing that, but it may be difficult/impossible to integrate it with other GCP products/services. The `Plain OAuth 2.0` *might* be what you're looking for (I don't understand it enough), search for it in the [Compare Auth Options](https://developers.google.com/identity/choose-auth) guide.

Comment: Ah, so the solution was to use Firebase auth with custom tokens. Yes, I saw Firebase, misunderstood what that service did, and forgot to check on it (was so wrapped up in reading about OAuth 2). This page is also useful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens